# android manifest merger failed error

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new to android. And am trying to include a library for pattern lock in my application.But it's showing error like this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:8:9-41
is also present at [com.github.pro100svitlo:lockpattern:0.9.3] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@string/lpv_app_name).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

And here is my manifest file for the library:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.example.lockpattern">

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/lpv_app_name">

</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my gradle app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.intel.patternverification2stepmethod"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.pro100svitlo:lockpattern:0.9.3'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: share your gradle app module file with question

Comment: Check the lib 'com.github.pro100svitlo:lockpattern:0.9.3' has string app-name which is conflicting with your current app...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to manifest

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Add this to application inside manifest

```
tools:node="replace"
```

Comment: Yeah.. I have included.But its showing the same error.